# Cannot access to app engine local dev server

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio

I'm devellopping an android app for my school project using android studio, I create a google app engine endpoint to acces a datastore, I follow those two tutorial:
    http://rominirani.com/2014/08/26/gradle-tutorial-part-9-cloud-endpoints-persistence-android-studio/
    https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/HelloEndpoints

So i create a new Module, put my google app id into the appengine-web.xml file, when I run it I get te message:

> INFOS: The admin console is running at `http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin`
>
> nov. 25, 2014 3:46:33 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl doStart
>
> INFOS: Dev App Server is now running

But here is my localhost[image]

I also try to change the port number in my gradle file by writing:

> appengine {
>
> ```
>    httpPort = 8080
> ```

But I obtain another error:[image]

Do anyone have an idea why my dev server isn't accessible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the error was prompt only with gogle chrome (maybe because i'm running it without admin privileges) but it's works great in safari.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to try with port number 8888 (look at your error message), where as your server is running at 8080 port number

If you want to change the port number, there is an .iml file inside the project, edit HTTP_PORT under configurations{}

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I tried different port number and I didn't take the good screenshot but your suggestion is not the correct answer, since I post this, I found out that the web app is avaiable with safari but not with chrome. Maybe because I'm running chrome without administrator privileges on mac. I will post answer to this for next people in my case.